# I cant locate the input box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

This is the error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="cardCvc-input"]"}
```

This is the html:

```
<input type="tel" name="cardCvc" id="cardCvc-input" autocomplete="off" required="" minlength="3" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}" cccvc="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
```

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(a)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress').send_keys('email')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('password\n')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id('cardCvc-input').send_keys('123')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-continue').click()
```

I have used tag name,id,class name and name still cant find this element

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct error message?  You're trying to find the element by ID, but the error message mentions css selector.

Comment: the last two row is the code of the error

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes it should be correct error message as if you use Id/ Name / class python selenium binding uses css selector only in turn.

Comment: @TanJooHui Can you check if there is any iframe in your page. Go to page inspect mode (F12) > Click on Element Tab > Do ctrl+F > search for //iframe and check if getting any match.

Comment: @rahulrai <iframe _ngcontent-lcc-c87="" scrolling="no" title="payment" src="https://gs-payments.nike.com/cvv?cardBrand=visa&amp;checkoutId=d7b98fa6-8790-482c-9d51-21d04377a163&amp;externalSessionId=29d79aed-f269-4e9a-ad75-596cd2766a23&amp;storedCardId=36c1e91e-e535-4e1a-97cd-d56a018d6bd6&amp;&amp;culture=en" class="cvv"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your elements are inside an iframe. So before interacting with elements you need to go inside the frame.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(a)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='payment']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress').send_keys('email')
```

**Note: **

1. You should not use implicit wait and time.sleep both together. As implicit wait is sufficient and better way to wait than time.sleep
2. Any time you need to come out of iframe use driver.switch_to.default_content().

Comment: Message: no such window

Comment: Can you please share at what line you are getting error and copy complete error message. Also please share HTML source code for elements you try to interact with and that of iframe. If possible please share page link.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/play2.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name('cardCvc').send_keys(580)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)

Comment: <iframe _ngcontent-mgg-c87="" scrolling="no" title="payment" src="https://gs-payments.nike.com/cvv?cardBrand=visa&amp;checkoutId=d8ff735a-d8e7-4eb2-9f47-75028d109faf&amp;externalSessionId=29d79aed-f269-4e9a-ad75-596cd2766a23&amp;storedCardId=36c1e91e-e535-4e1a-97cd-d56a018d6bd6&amp;&amp;culture=en" class="cvv" cd_frame_id_="ea9764d8f9a612e258a6ba4dedc7a7d7"></iframe>

Comment: <input type="tel" name="cardCvc" id="cardCvc-input" autocomplete="off" required="" minlength="3" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}" cccvc="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">